# Got stuck with simple (is it?) nonlinear first-order ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Trying to solve the following differential equation:

$u' + \frac{1}{2} u^2 = -\frac{a}{cosh^2 (x)}-k$

Following the regular method I first solved the corresponding uniform ODE:

$ u'  + \frac{1}{2} u^2 = 0 \\
-\frac{du}{u^2} = \frac{1}{2}dx \\
\frac{1}{u} = \frac{x+C}{2} \\
u = \frac{2}{x+C} $

Next, to find a particular solution of non-uniform equation I replace C with some function of independent variable: $C \rightarrow f(x)$

$ u(x) = \frac{2}{x+f} \\
u'(x) = - \frac{2(1+f')}{(x+f)^2} \\
- \frac{2(1+f')}{(x+f)^2} + \frac{2}{(x+f)^2} = -\frac{a}{cosh^2(x)}-k \\
\frac{-f'}{(x+f)^2} = -\frac{a}{cosh^2(x)} -k$

And I'm totally stuck. Any ideas?

EDIT: Originally the ODE was retrieved from following PDE:

$H_{xx} + H_{yy} + \frac{1}{4} H_y ^2 + \frac{1}{4} H_x ^2 + \cot(y) H_y -1 = 0$

Where the indices denote derivatives over corresponding variables. The PDE itself comes from more complicated PDE after the substitution $H(x,y) = \ln F(x,y)$ and some algebra.

I'll be more than happy if there's some more convenient method of solving it.

EDIT2: just noticed that PDE is not the correct one. Still, if there are any convenient methods of solving it, feel free to post.

Comment: From Wolfram|Alpha, I got some horrifying looking solution...

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D+u%5E2+%3D+-%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7B%5Ccosh%5E2+(x)%7D,+x+is+real

Comment: Quite strange. When I fed the equation to Wolfram Mathematica, it just didn't give me any solution.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've discovered that I forgot a term in the equation. Will edit the question.

Comment: what are you using the DE for though? If you have the initial conditions the solutions might get simpler.

Comment: @Karn, I've got it after separating the variables in a PDE. The PDE itself comes from Einstein equation in bispherical coordinates.

Comment: @Tajimura : Why not editing the PDE ? So, one could see if there is a more convenient method to solve it.

Comment: @JJacquelin, our whole group spent about 5 hours storming that PDE with different methods, and the only thing we come up with is the separation. It is not "true" separation (as in Fourier's method), but, rather, constraining the equation to have a solution of the form $H(x,y) = U(x)V(y)$. Also, PDE is nonlinear too. Including it in the question body is a good idea, but, unfortunately, i didn't copy the files (*.nb) from my workstation to my laptop and I've only written down the ODEs got by separation.

Comment: the solution containes the Legendre function

Comment: @JJacquelin, I managed to retrieve modified form of original PDE. Edited it into the question.

Comment: @Dr. Graubner, I'm okay with Legendre polinomials.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is non-linear, so the whole mechanism with homogeneous and inhomogeneous solutions does not work.

You can set $u=2\dfrac{v'}{v}$, $u'=2\dfrac{v''v-v'^2}{v^2}$ so that
$$
u'+\frac12u^2=2\frac{v''}{v}=f(x)
$$
gives a linear ODE of second order
$$
v''(x)-\frac12f(x)v(x)=0
$$
which still is usually not symbolically solvable but gives you more equations with named solutions to compare to. Also, a power series solution might be easier to compute in this form.

Comment: Schrödinger! Great :)

Answer (score 0):

$$u' + \frac{1}{2} u^2 = -\frac{a}{\cosh^2 (x)}-k$$
Let $u=2\frac{v'}{v} \quad\to\quad u'=2\frac{v''}{v}-2\frac{v'^2}{v^2}$

$2\frac{v''}{v}-2\frac{v'^2}{v^2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(2\frac{v'}{v}\right)^2 = -\frac{a}{\cosh^2 (x)}-k$

$$v'' +\left(\frac{a}{2\cosh^2 (x)}+\frac{k}{2}\right)v=0 \tag 1$$
This is a second order linear ODE of the kind : 
$$\quad v''+f(x)\:v=0\quad$$ 
where $f(x)$ is a known function.

It is well known that this kind of ODEs are not always analytically solvable. Some of them are solvable in terms of special functions. For example if $f(x)=\frac{A}{x^2}+\frac{B}{x}+C$ the solutions involve the Kummer and Whittaker functions. In case of $f(x)=Cx^p$ the solutions involve the Bessel functions. A few other examples can be found involving some standard special functions.

Unfortunately, the case $\quad f(x)=-\frac{a}{\cosh^2 (x)}-k\quad$ is not known, as far as I know. On my opinion, you cannot expect a solution of Eq.$(1)$ on closed form until a new family of special functions be created and standardized.

In such circumstances, other approaches such as series expansion or numerical calculus could provide approximate results.